# Unable to run different class files for a java application in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

```
./gradle -Prun=com.foo.Bar
./gradle -Prun=com.foo.Baz
```

Unable to run different class files for a java application in gradle as mentioned above using the following definition. What am I missing here

```
application {
    mainClassName = project.findProperty("run").toString()
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What happens instead? Any error message you can share?

Comment: It just doesn't go into the main class at all, there are no errors

Comment: Did you try using `mainClass` instead of `mainClassName`?